# Java hibernate. How to get a entity where a date field is oldest using the criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity `DataStatus` with the field `date`.

My goal is get the oldest row by `date` field.

```
public DataStatus getOldest(){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DataStatus.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("date", MIN));
    List<DataStatus> results = criteria.list();
    if(results.size()<1)return null;
    return results.get(0);
}
```

Comment: What is MIN? What do you exactly want to achieve? Get the DataStatus that has the smallest date of all DataStatus? If so, use `order by date`, and call setMaxResults(1) on the query

Comment: With MIN I wanted to show my goal for find the minimum date. Something like sql "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date =  MIN(date) "

Comment: With the query on top I try to show what I want to get :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User order by mechanism from criteria API

```
CriteriaQuery<DataStatus> q = cb.createQuery(DataStatus.class);
Root<DataStatus> c = q.from(DataStatus.class);
q.select(c);
q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get("date")));
```

Comment: This should be the right question. Regarding to find the lower or higher value there is no other way than sorting the entities by a desired field, in your case the Date field.

Comment: If I have a table with millions records and I want get only oldest one . From answer on top, firstly I should get all rows then i should sort by asc and take first element from list? It sound strangely for me :)

Comment: @EdgarasKarka if you call setMaxResults(1) on the query, you won't get all rows. Just the first (i.e. oldest) one.

Comment: @JBNizet Maybe you can show a example how can get the row where a field `date` is minimum/oldest in table without sorting.

Comment: You need sorting. The answer here is correct. I just lackes the call to setMaxResults(1). If you have an index on the date, this query should be very fast.